# seeking combinations (strstr) of letters in external file

Tags: c

I have a task to make smth like t9 like it was in old phones (number can also mean some combination of letters). For example, if user run it this way `./t9search 23 < list.txt`, program should return numbers which has this combination of digits or letters that corresponds to them (in this case a,b,c and d,e,f). It's also forbidden to work with dynamic memory(malloc, free) and functions with algorithms (qsort, lsearch etc). Format of information in file is "name\n number\n name\n number\n...".
The loop doesn't work correctly but I can't find a mistake. The program should return `{Name}, {number}`but it return only numbers.
The code is:

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FULFILLED 1
#define NOT_FULFILLED 0

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char line[99];
    int line_no = -1;
    int size = strlen(argv[1]);
    char letters[size][5];
    int total_combinations = 1;
    char combinations[total_combinations][size + 1];
    int current_combination[size];
    int check_name = NOT_FULFILLED;
    char name[99];

    for(int i = 0; argv[1][i]; i++)
    {
        switch(argv[1][i])              //cases according to input
        {
            case '0':
                strcpy(letters[i], "+");
                break;
            case '2':
                strcpy(letters[i], "abc");
                break;
            case '3':
                strcpy(letters[i], "def");
                break;
            case '4':
                strcpy(letters[i], "ghi");
                break;
            case '5':
                strcpy(letters[i], "jkl");
                break;
            case '6':
                strcpy(letters[i], "mno");
                break;
            case '7':
                strcpy(letters[i], "pqrs");
                break;
            case '8':
                strcpy(letters[i], "tuv");
                break;
            case '9':
                strcpy(letters[i], "wxyz");
                break;
        }
        total_combinations *= strlen(letters[i]);   //number of combinations of letters from array elements
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        current_combination[i] = 0;
    }
        int k = 0;
        
    while (k < total_combinations)
    {
        for (int set_idx = 0; set_idx < size; set_idx++)
        {
            int letter_idx = current_combination[set_idx];
            combinations[k][set_idx] = letters[set_idx][letter_idx];
        }
        combinations[k][size] = '\0';
            for(int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {   
            current_combination[i]++;
            if (current_combination[i] == strlen(letters[i]))
            {
                current_combination[i] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        k++;
        }
        
    
                
    printf("%c\n", sizeof(combinations)/sizeof(combinations[0]));   
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin))
    {
        line_no++;
        if (line_no % 2 == 0) //even lines (names)
        {
            name[99] = line; //variable to use name with number
            for (int i = 0; i < total_combinations; i++) //for each combination from array with combinations
            {
                if (strstr(line, combinations[i])) //if combination is a substring of a string
                {
                    check_name = FULFILLED;
                }
            }
        }
    
        else if (line_no % 2 == 1) //odd lines (numbers)
        {
            if (check_name == FULFILLED || strstr(line, argv[1])) // if there's name that corresponds with input OR input is a substring of a string
            {
                printf("%s, %s", name, line);
                check_name = NOT_FULFILLED;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

I've tried to change the way of checking names:

```
        if (line_no % 2 == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= strlen(letters); j++)
            {
                char let = getchar();
                
                for (int i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++)
                {
                    if (letters[j] == line[i])
                    {
                        check_name = FULFILLED;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (letters[j] != line [i])
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
```

Sure I didn't reach success. So I'd be extremely grateful for any help.

Comment: This array is created when `total_combinations == 1`. `char combinations[total_combinations][size + 1];`, then `total_combinations` is increased and used to index into `combinations` out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays do not resize reflectively when the variables used to create them change. They are sized permanently at the time of their initialization. The following

```
int total_combinations = 1;
char combinations[total_combinations][size + 1];
/* ... */
total_combinations *= strlen(letters[i]);
```

does not cause `combinations` to grow as `total_combinations` does. Move the definition of `combinations` to after `total_combinations` has been fully computed.

The following attempts to assign a `char *` to a `char`, and also indexes `name` out of bounds.

```
name[99] = line;
```

As done previously, use `strcpy` to copy strings.

Note that, if found and if there is room in the buffer, `fgets` stores the newline character in the buffer, so

```
printf("%s, %s", name, line);
```

will very likely print staggered output, like

```
Alice
, 5551234567
```

---

A cursory refactoring:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *remove_newline(char *string)
{
    if (string)
        string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = '\0';

    return string;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s t9_sequence\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int size = strlen(argv[1]);
    char letters[size][5];
    int total_combinations = 1;
    int current_combination[size];

    for (int i = 0; argv[1][i]; i++) {
        switch (argv[1][i]) {
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input: \"%c\"\n", argv[1][i]);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            case '0':
                strcpy(letters[i], "+");
                break;
            case '2':
                strcpy(letters[i], "abc");
                break;
            case '3':
                strcpy(letters[i], "def");
                break;
            case '4':
                strcpy(letters[i], "ghi");
                break;
            case '5':
                strcpy(letters[i], "jkl");
                break;
            case '6':
                strcpy(letters[i], "mno");
                break;
            case '7':
                strcpy(letters[i], "pqrs");
                break;
            case '8':
                strcpy(letters[i], "tuv");
                break;
            case '9':
                strcpy(letters[i], "wxyz");
                break;
        }

        total_combinations *= strlen(letters[i]);
    }

    memset(current_combination, 0, sizeof current_combination);

    char combinations[total_combinations][size + 1];

    for (int k = 0; k < total_combinations; k++) {
        for (int set_idx = 0; set_idx < size; set_idx++) {
            int letter_idx = current_combination[set_idx];
            combinations[k][set_idx] = letters[set_idx][letter_idx];
        }

        combinations[k][size] = '\0';

        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            current_combination[i]++;

            if (current_combination[i] != strlen(letters[i]))
                break;

            current_combination[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    char name[128];
    char number[128];

    while (1) {
        if (!fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin))
            break;

        if (!fgets(number, sizeof number, stdin))
            break;

        int found = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < total_combinations; i++) {
            if (strstr(name, combinations[i])) {
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found || strstr(number, argv[1]))
            printf("%s, %s\n", remove_newline(name), remove_newline(number));
    }
}
```